# Command in Ubuntu 18.04 that returns tabular information about external drives like the old `fdisk` did

Tags: command-line, mount, filesystem, fdisk

In the good old days before the output format of `fdisk` was changed, as illustrated in [this link](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-disk-partitions/), I could obtain the file system type of an external drive with a command like `sudo fdisk -l | grep sd` and then the approriate `cut` command.     With the new version of `fdisk` the output is not in table format so I can't do this.    I can learn the filesystem type from the `parted -l` command but it outputs puts filesystem type and the drive name on different lines, so it's harder to get the information I want from a single command line alias.      Is there a way to get the tabular information that `fdisk` used to provide, or, as a plan B, install the old version of `fdisk` on 18.04

Comment: My `sudo fdisk -l` output looks like the link you refer to as in the good old days.. except for the additional column of 'Size'.  Is that really a problem?  as changing your `cut` can't be difficult  (*my release is later than 18.04, but i doubt much as changed between 2.31.1 & 2.33.1*)

Comment: lsblk may be helpful here. Try with something like: `lsblk -o NAME,TYPE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT`

Comment: lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE   gives me exactly what I want, thanks!      Could you convert it to an answer and I'll accept it?